# Do we say "He roared his motorbike noisily to show people that how cool he is"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

There are some young people with low self-esteem, they often speed up their motorbikes suddenly make a deep, very loud noise and to show off or to get attention.

Can we use the verb "**roar**" to express that?

> **[roar](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/roar)** 4 [intransitive always + adverb/preposition] if a vehicle roars
>   somewhere, it moves very quickly and noisily
>
> The car roared off down the road.

---

So we say "**His motorbike roared off down the road.**" but the verb is an intransitive and not a transitive verb.

can we say "**He roared his motorbike noisily to show people that how cool he is**"?

or **are there any other ways to express it?**

Comment: There is a also transitive definition: #2. Definition #4 needs an adverb or a preposition. Their example is "The car roared **off** down the road".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to express it: "He revved his motorbike noisily."

[American Heritage Dictionary "rev" 1a](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rev)

a. To increase the speed of (a motor, for example): revved the engine.

The word "noisily" already conveys the sonic nuisance.
Another possibility: "He revved his motorbike [aggressively], making the engine roar."